# R's coxph won't converge when I include factor (categorical) variables

Tags: r, categorical-data, convergence, cox-model

I have a dataset of 371 observations. When I run `coxph` with numeric variables it works fine. However, when I try to add factor (categorical) variables it returns “Ran out of iterations and the model did not converge”.

Of note, when I restructure all factors to binary variables with dummy and use glmnet-lasso the model converges.

Here are examples of the code and output (including summary description of the variables):

```
> maxSTree.cox <- coxph (Surv(time,status)~Chemo_Simple, data=dataset)

Warning message:
In fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
  Ran out of iterations and did not converge

> summary (dataset$Chemo_Simple)
         Anthra-HDAC       Anthra-Plus       ArsenicAtra              ATRA           ATRA-GO 
                0               163                 2                12                 0                 2 
         ATRA_IDA Demeth-HistoneDAC          Flu-HDAC     Flu-HDAC-plus         HDAC-Clof         HDAC-only 
                0                34                37                 4                24                 1 
        HDAC-Plus        LowArac+/-       LowDAC-Clof         MYLO+IL11    No Rx in MDACC            Phase1 
                4                 8                30                 5                 1                 5 
              SCT    StdARAC-Anthra      StdAraC-Plus          Targeted         VNP40101M 
                0                 0                 0                13                23
```

Answer (score 1):

`coxph()` takes an argument `control` which expects to be passed an object produced by `coxph.control()`.

From `?coxph.control` we see that there are two arguments related to the number of iterations `iter.max` and `outer.max`. You can try to increase the `iter.max` value so you call would be

```
coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Chemo_Simple, data = dataset,
      control = coxph.control(iter.max = 50))
```

And then see if that converges. `outer.max` is not relevant here as your model doesn't contain any `pspline` terms.

Also, consider changing the starting values via argument `init` to `coxph()`. You could use the starting values from lasso fit for example assuming they are on the same scale/for the same parameters as the `coxph()` implementation.

Comment: Thank you ! I tried to increase the number of iteration but it did not work. I think the problem is that I have too many levels in my factors compared to the number of events in the dataset. I have also run lasso (glmnet). Indeed it gets the model to converge. Oddly, when I try to use the betas, build a coxph model and evaluate it in pec (which retrains and test the model using bootstrap cross validation) the prediction matrix from refitting the model is different than the size of the testset. I will post it in a separate question with code samples. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Here is a link to the follow up question  [link] (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63530/problem-with-bootcv-for-coxph-in-pec-after-feature-selection-with-glmnet-lasso)

Answer (score 1):

The factor variable dataset$Chemo_Simple has a couple of levels with only 1 occurrence. Standard error for those two levels would be 0 and hence z value would be Inf or -Inf which would make convergence impossible.

You can confirm if my answer is valid in your case by looking at the result of summary(maxSTree.cox).